# redis scan over a particular key which is type of list

Tags: javascript, redis

I am trying to iterate over a list in redis, which has huge length and lrange causes JS to crash.

> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_2 Allocation failed - process out of memory
>   FATAL ERROR: JS Allocation failed - process out of memory

I searched for scan but it only gives you matching result in keys and cannot use it for iterating over a key which is a type of list.

```
redis-cli: scan 0 MATCH my:key
redis-cli: 1) 18
redis-cli: 2) my:key
redis-cli: type my:key
redis-cli: list
```

Now, I want to iterate over my:key using scan, but unable to find any syntax for it.

Answer (score 6):

No, you **CANNOT** use `SCAN` command to iterate a list. `SCAN` is used for iterating the key space.

Instead, you should use `LRANGE` to iterate the list.

```
// Get the first 10 items in the list.
LRANGE list 0 9
// Get the next 10 items
LRANGE list 10 19
// ... until all items have been iterated.
```

However, since the time complexity of `LRANGE` is `O(S+N)`, this is **NOT** a cheap operation, especially when the list is huge. When you use `LRANGE` to get the 100th item, Redis has to iterate the first `99` items.

So I think you should re-design your system to split the list into several small lists, or use other data structures.